# Why $\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sqrt{\sec^2 x}} \ne \sec x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

When I evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}(\sinh^{-1}(\tan x))$, I get

$$\frac{\sec^2 x }{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 x}}.$$

At this point I want to use the $\sec^2 x = 1 + \tan^2 x$ identity to simplify to:

$$\frac{\sec^2 x }{\sec x }= \sec x$$

Why is this improper?

Thank you for the help

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ only when $x$ is non-negative.  If $x$ could potentially be negative, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, which is not only messier, but may not cancel the way you want it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, you get
$$
\frac{\sec^2 x }{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2 x}}
= \frac{\sec^2 x}{\sqrt{\sec^2 x}}
= \frac{\sec^2 x}{|\sec x|}
= |\sec x|.
$$